# Why is there stil a OutOfMemory from SoftReference?

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory

There will be a OOM error in creating so many Strong Reference is because of GC won't collect Strong Reference, but GC will collect Weak Reference if there no extra memory. So my question is :
I create a loop to create Weak Reference while I set my `-Xmx2M`

```
Set<SoftReference<Integer>> sa = new HashSet<~>();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     SoftReference<Integer> ref = new SoftReference<Integer>(i);
     sa.add(ref);
}
```

It's still occur OOM, Why?

Comment: i < size what is size?

Answer (score 7):

> It's still occur OOM, Why?

The `Integer`s are being cleaned up however the `HashSet` and the `SoftReference`s don't get removed by the GC.  Note: A `SoftReference` object is larger than an `Integer` object.

What you can do is the follow to never run out of memory.

```
SoftReference<HashSet<Integer>>> sa = null;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (sa == null || sa.get() == null)
        sa = new SoftReference<HashSet<Integer>>(new HashSet<Integer>());
    sa.get().add(ref);
}
```